# When I'm looking for a particular iPhone feature for my iPhone app, how do I know what class or framework to look for in Xcode documentation?

Tags: ios, xcode, api, ios5

When I'm looking for a particular iPhone feature for my iPhone/iPad app, how do I know what class or framework to look for in Xcode documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer.apple.com provides the best documentation.  For example the UIAccelerometer page at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html

says at the top that it is part of the framework **/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework Framework**

Answer (score 0):

Google  plus iOS developer site, e.g.:

```
video site:developer.apple.com/library/ios
```